# Change format of data in file using boost::regex

Tags: c++, regex, date, boost

I have file output.txt, in file we can find something like:

```
01/01/2015  15:00:00      2222.2222
2222.2222 2222.2222 2222.2222 
04/04/2015  15:00:00      2222.2222
```

and i would like to change format from `DD/MM/RRRR HH:MM:SS` to `RRRR-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.000` using boost regex. But I have no clue how should I type pattern.

Anyone use boost regex and could help me?

Comment: I don't think regular expressions are the right tool to change format of date-time stamps (also see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems). Instead parse it as a date-time of one format, then it's simple to output in any format possible.

Comment: Ok, but it's not that simple, I was thinking about parsing file, getting line by line but it's hard to replace one pattern with another

Comment: Did my answer solve the issue?

Answer (score 3):

You can use code like this (adaptation of an example at [Boost C++ Libraries](http://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.regex)):

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::string s = "01/30/2015 15:00:00 2222.2222";
  boost::regex expr{"([0-9]{2})\\/([0-9]{2})\\/([0-9]{4})\\s+([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})\\s+[0-9]{4}\\.[0-9]{4}"};
  std::string fmt{"\\3/\\1/\\2 \\4:\\5:\\6.000"};
  std::cout << boost::regex_replace(s, expr, fmt) << '\n';
}
```

[A demo of what the regex is doing](https://regex101.com/r/mW6wL0/1)